# Javascript/Canvas - find mouse coords relative to the location of the coordinate grid

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have made a little toy thing that would get the angle of my mouse in relation to the center point on the canvas. I attempted to make it so I can click to move that point, and came up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Strontium/7htLjvqs/

I have figured out how to make it so I can change the center point once without things acting weird, but passed that, I don't know what to do. I know what this is the case, though. It's because it is checking the relation between the original location of the coordinate grid and the new one, but after I move it, the numbers I used are no longer valid.

I need a way to get the location of the coordinate grid after using `ctx.translate()`, but I am not sure if that is even possible.

Comment: Why not just move the center point of your drawing instead of moving the canvas?

Comment: @Secret Oh man I am stupid, I'll try that and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of moving the whole canvas, why not just move the center point of your 'toy thing'?

So instead of

```
//move the location of the coordinate grid on click
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    gridOffsetX = mousePos.x - 250;
    gridOffsetY = mousePos.y - 250;
    ctx.translate(gridOffsetX, gridOffsetY);
}, false);

var centerPoint = {x: 250, y:250}
//move the location of the coordinate grid on click
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    centerPoint = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
}, false);
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/7264eahd/

Comment: I tried this when you first suggested it to me (before I saw this) and I got it working, also getting rid of my gridOffset vars. Thanks!